# How to make Medium.com like Navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

Is there a way to make [medium.com](http://medium.com) like Navbar that can be scroll horizontally in touch devices. The best the way if there is no js is requier because I need it clean with css.

Here is how far I've got. But there is a scroll bar appearing in desktop browsers while the medium.com's navbar is not.

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Sports</li>
  <li>International</li>
  <li>Political</li>
  <li>TV News</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WaiLinAung/b3nwcq14/#&togetherjs=k9T0jGRcUc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use overflow-x.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/DollarChills/pen/dVKMxB)

Add this between your  tags. This is for responsive design.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        ul {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
  <li>Link 4</li>
  <li>Link 5</li>
  <li>Link 6</li>
  <li>Link 7</li>
  <li>Link 8</li>
  <li>Link 9</li>
  <li>Link 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What I want is not the fixed top feature. I want the navbar to be hroizontally scrollable in small screen. Instead of wrapping eveything in humberger, I want every links as it is and user can see them by scrolling horizontally.

Comment: Thanks it is scrollable but the I want the scrollbar to be hidden. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hidden on the desktop, and only available on a device? Or do you mean transparent background?

Comment: I mean when in desktop browsers, the scroll bar is shown. Especially when mouse is plugged. Is there a way to not to show the scrollbar?

Comment: This can be done using media queries. See updated answer. If a window is 768px or less the <ul> menu will show.

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display:inline-flex;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: gray;
}
ul li a:hover{
color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="sports.html">Sports</a></li>
  <li><a href="international.html">International</a></li>
  <li><a href="political.html">Political</a></li>
  <li><a href="tvnews.html">TV </a></li>
  <li><a href="political.html">Political</a></li>
  <li><a href="tvnews.html">TV </a></li>
  <li><a href="political.html">Political</a></li>
  <li><a href="tvnews.html">TV </a></li>
  <li><a href="political.html">Political</a></li>
  <li><a href="tvnews.html">TV </a></li>
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is just a navbar that can't scroll horizontally.

Comment: @Wai Lin Aung please check again,changed